# Custom Post Type - Same Post Name, Different Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

I have 4 Custom Post Types:

- Services
- FAQs
- Prices
- Before and After

I want to be able to have the same post names within each of these post types, example:

> Services
>   Skin (example.com/Services/skin)
>   Cream
>   (example.com/Services/cream)
>   Body (example.com/Services/body)
>
> FAQs
>   Skin (example.com/FAQs/skin)
>   Cream
>   (example.com/FAQs/cream)
>   Body (example.com/FAQs/body)
>
> Prices
>   Skin (example.com/Prices/skin)
>   Cream
>   (example.com/Prices/cream)
>   Body (example.com/Prices/body)
>
> Before and After
>   Skin (example.com/before-and-after/skin)
>   Cream
>   (example.com/before-and-after/cream)
>   Body (example.com/before-and-after/body)

How can I do this? Right now if I make a new post with the same name as a current one, it adds a "-2" or "-3" to the end of the posts slug:

BAD:

> example.com/services/body
>
> example.com/faqs/body-2
>
> example.com/prices/body-3
>
> example.com/before-and-after/body-4

```
add_action('init', 'create_post_type_html5'); // Add our HTML5 Blank Custom Post Type
function create_post_type_html5()
 {
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'html5-blank'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'html5-blank');
register_post_type('html5-blank', // Register Custom Post Type
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Services', 'html5blank'), // Rename these to suit
        'singular_name' => __('Services', 'html5blank'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'html5blank'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Services', 'html5blank'),
        'edit' => __('Edit', 'html5blank'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Services', 'html5blank'),
        'new_item' => __('New Services', 'html5blank'),
        'view' => __('View Services', 'html5blank'),
        'view_item' => __('View Services', 'html5blank'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Services', 'html5blank'),
        'not_found' => __('No Servicess found', 'html5blank'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Service\'s found in Trash', 'html5blank')
    ),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'service','with_front' => true),
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'thumbnail'
    ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
    'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
    'taxonomies' => array(
        'post_tag',
        'category'
    ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
));


 }
```

Comment: I assume you are running that code several times to create your four different types? I just tried this with a couple of post types on a site I maintain, and I can't duplicate the problem. I **can** add identical post names in the different post type. Possibly this has something to do with your permalink settings?

Comment: Are you trying to enter services/skin as a slug?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, it's quite irritating... One thing I did notice about you configuration is that the first parameter you pass to `register_post_type` isn't actually the name of the post type; just confirming that in your instance it is unique for each post type?

Comment: Also, just to confirm, did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this problem as well; in my case this issue was resolved when a *maximum of one post type* is to `'hierarchical' => true`. The others need to be set to `'hierarchical' => false`. After each adjustment I would refresh the permalink settings in Settings > Permalinks.

This and this was the change that enabled the functionality for me; it may not be the only etting that contributed to this issue; I'd be curious to see whether this has effected others...